# Selecting from database with offsets

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter

```
 <?php
      switch ($page)
        {
        case 1:

            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 28, 0);
            break;
        case 2:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 56, 29);
            break;
        case 3:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 84, 57);
            break;
        case 4:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 112, 85);
            break;
        case 5:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 140, 113);
            break;
        case 6:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 168, 141);
            break;
        case 7:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 196, 169);
             break;
        case 8:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 224, 197);
             break;
        case 9:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 252, 225);
             break;
        case 10:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 280, 253);
            break;
        case 11:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 308, 281);
            break;
        case 12:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 336, 309);
            break;
        case 13:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 364, 337);
            break;
        case 14:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 392, 365);
            break;
        case 15:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 420, 393);
            break;                  
        default:
            $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 28, 0);
```

}

?>

This is what i'm currently doing.. Is there a better way to do this? Each case is a page and i'm calling that from page/$num

How would I get the 28 NEWEST entries from the same thing i'm trying to achieve above?

---

Update from Robert Pitt

- `$page = 2; //page 2`
- `$limit = 30; //per page`
- `$offset = ($page - 1 * $offset); //30`

Then you query your database like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $offset,$limit
```

Comment: why are you hard coding pages, should you not be calculating the offset from the limit and the page such as `$offset = ($page * $limit)` where `$limit` would be the per page?

Comment: You should see that your limit and offset are clearly mathematically related to $page, you just need to put that math into your code. One line, not 50+

Comment: @RobertPitt I'm not sure what you mean? What should I change in my code?

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I don't know why I did it that way, but that's a good point you have there.

Comment: haven't read the whole post, but CI does have a built in pagination library - surely that would do what you're after without all this hassle ~ http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only two queries for unlimited pages:

```
<?php
    switch($page) {
       case 1:
          $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 28, 0);
          break;
       default:
          $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), 28 * (int)$page, 28 * (int)$page - 27);
          break;
    }
?>
```

Optionally, you can store the page size in a variable and use that, instead of hardcoding it:

```
<?php
    $ps = 28; // page size
    switch($page) {
       case 1:
          $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), $ps, 0);
          break;
       default:
          $query = $this->db->get_where('ao', array('banned' => '0'), $ps * (int)$page, $ps * (int)$page - ($ps - 1));
          break;
    }
?>
```

This way, you can change the page size by changing one variable, instead of doing a find/replace in all of the code.

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say storing the page size? EDIT: Also does this display the results for the newest entries first?

Comment: Thank you! I have a better understanding now, so much simpler than what I was doing.. This is displaying the results from the beginning(oldest), is there anyway to flip it around and display the newest entries?

Comment: `28 * ($page - 1)` is what you need, thus only 1 query, as 28 * 0 + 28

Comment: @RobertPitt Is that the answer to my question in the previous comment, or is that directed at Merijn?

Comment: I think it's a comment on my code. I didn't reduce it to one case because then the first record would be 1 instead of 0, but I might have misread.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help:

```
$sqltorun="SET @rownum = 0;
SET @startRow = ".$StartRow."; # your $page
SET @maxRows = ".$MaxRows."; # limit. how much rows per page
SELECT * FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, YOURTABLE t where banned=>0 order by SOMETHING OR DONT ORDERBY) t WHERE rownum BETWEEN @startRow and @startRow + @maxRows and rownum!=@startRow";
```

Comment: That would not work if new entries are inserted and items should be bumped to a new page. Calculating the items on a page dynamically would be better.